# Python - bisection method crashes whole application

Tags: python, crash, bisection

I have strange problem with my window application. It's task is to compute roots of polynomial of n-degree with bisection method or secant method, it depends on user will. And now my problem starts because if I will put certain interval into the method, it crashes sometimes after first click of star button but if it makes through first time, on second time if I adjust interval [a,b] and punt into "a"   result of first go, it crashes without error. I'm not even mentioning that my secant method is going nuts, for some intervals answers are good, for some they are just random.

```
    def secant(self,f, a, b, err):
        fb=f(b)
        while np.absolute(fb)>err:
            midPoint=b-(b-a)*fb/(fb-f(a))
            a=b
            b=midPoint
            fb=f(b)
        return b
#--------------------------------------------------------------
    def bisection(self,f,a,b,err):
        while np.absolute(b-a)>err:
            midPoint=(a+b)*0.5
            if f(midPoint)*f(a)<0:
                b=midPoint
            midPoint=(a+b)*0.5
            if f(midPoint)*f(b)<0:
                a=midPoint
            midPoint=(a+b)*0.5
        return midPoint
```

Comment: Your program stays in an infinite loop when after a while f(a) == 0 or f(b) == 0.

Comment: How i can avoid this? I do not see any solution to deal with this problem

Comment: You should test for f(a) or f(b) == 0 and then return a or b

Comment: I don't know, now i have tired to implement if f(a)==0 return a and same for b but it still is crashing on certain intervals

Comment: Print out the values of a, b, f(a), and f(b) at each step to see what is happening.

Comment: You were right, it entered infinity loop for polynomial 6x^6+10x*2-9x and keeps printing same value of a,b and also same value for f(a),f(b). But now i don't know what should i change because it will happen to all intervals where a=|b| due to statement in while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def bisect(f, a, b, e):
    """ Bisection Method

    inputs:
    f - a function.
    a - Starting interval
    b - Ending interval
    e - Acceptable value for 0; (e.g. consider 0.001 == 0)
    """

    iterations = 0
    while True:
        c = (a + b)/2
        if b - c <= e:
            print('Iterated:', iterations, 'times.')
            return c
        elif f(b)*f(c) <= 0:
            a = c
        else:
            b = c
        iterations += 1
```

Check out more [here](https://github.com/synchronizing/Numercial-Analysis/blob/master/Root%20Finding%20Methods/Bisection%20Method.ipynb).